Posting YouTube Live Stream on Facebook misbehaves?
Whenever I post the URL of a YouTube Live Stream to Facebook, it has the right image, but in a desktop browser it turns into a strange "Send Message" chat link, no matter where I click on it. This is the case in a desktop browser, however on a mobile device it correctly links to the YouTube Stream! Here's a shared link - the shared link works fine as it does on mobile devies, but on a desktop the actual post takes you to "Send Message" chat instead. Here's a screenshot of how it actually appears in Facebook. Does anyone know what's up with that and how to avoid it?
